# Lubuntu loops between the terminal pre-login and an odd, glitchy screen for a couple of frames

Tags: command-line, gnome, lubuntu, login

I installed Gnome on lubuntu and I attempted to change some fonts and clock settings. The problem started when I Logged out and tried to login to Gnome again. I assumed I made at least on mistake by either re configuring fonts or the clock format(I'm betting on the fonts). Restarting the computer now takes lubuntu into a loop between a black screen, a single frame of a glitchy graphic and a single frame of the login terminal. If I could just reset the desktop environments through my installer image via terminal, that might do the trick. I would normally google it but that landed me with no results. Thanks in advance.